# Names of Students as Watermarks of Exam Questionnaire

Tags: watermark

I want to generate copies of the same exam questionnaire such that each questionnaire has a (different) name of a student as watermark. I have a .csv file containing the names of my students, and I intend to use background package.

Comment: This seems a good plan... ;-)

Comment: Jokes apart --- please try it, and if you got stuck, post here an example and somebody will help.